# Given a biological dataset with measurements over a year, how can I identify seasonal variation, if any?

Tags: r, regression, modeling, biostatistics, seasonality

I have a biological dataset and I am interested in answering the following question:

Are the measurements dependent on time-of-year/season?

I use R for my analyses

Answer (score 1):

You start by plotting your measurement against time of year and you look at that graph and see if such seasonality is present. Maybe you are done, maybe you need to do more. That depends on the finer details of your project.